# Text won't place above image and is attaching instead

Tags: html, css

I'm basically trying to put a header and then like 150px under it the image with its caption. However my text is attaching to the image and moves down with it.

```css
figure {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-top:
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  margin-top: -300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="D:\Documents\Coding\html-css practice.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Cod vanguard review</title>
<div>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://www.callofduty.com/content/dam/atvi/callofduty/cod-touchui/blog/hero/vgd/VGD-Campaign-Overview-TOUT.jpg">
    <figcaption>
      The Campaign Image For The New Call Of Duty
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Call of duty vanguard review</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Just so that it's clear.... Your text about "The campaign Image...." does appear as a caption perfectly normally beneath the image. Your header is indeed covering the image. You only want to change the header??

Comment: I want to move the image and the caption down and let the header stay in place. Every time I try to move the image and caption down the header moves with it.

Comment: Have you tried putting `<h1>` just before `<figure>`. `h1` might not need to be inside a Div, simply move it up in your code. At the moment it is way down in your code meaning it appears down the page a little but then you're trying to move it up the page using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Just invert your divs ...

```css
figure {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-top:
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="D:\Documents\Coding\html-css practice.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Cod vanguard review</title>
<div>
  <h1>Call of duty vanguard review</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://www.callofduty.com/content/dam/atvi/callofduty/cod-touchui/blog/hero/vgd/VGD-Campaign-Overview-TOUT.jpg">
    <figcaption>
      The Campaign Image For The New Call Of Duty
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly how I was thinking above. The h1 is way way down in your code and then you are trying to move it up the page using CSS. As Tony says here, just put the h1 above the image in your code. The h1 might not even need a Div around it.

Comment: I'm confused why inverting it changed anything. Like is there a rule in html that goes off the order.

Comment: @Youssef1781 of course the order have his meaning. Your items are created in order your declare it.

Answer (score 1):

Placing your "header" above the image would help.
Then give the header a `margin-bottom` with the desired amount of pixels.
Placing it under the image and creating a negative `margin-top` is an anti-pattern

```css
figure {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-top:
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="D:\Documents\Coding\html-css practice.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Cod vanguard review</title>
<div>
<div>
  <h1>Call of duty vanguard review</h1>
</div>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://www.callofduty.com/content/dam/atvi/callofduty/cod-touchui/blog/hero/vgd/VGD-Campaign-Overview-TOUT.jpg">
    <figcaption>
      The Campaign Image For The New Call Of Duty
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work if you simply put `<h1>` above `<figure>` like this.....

```
<div>
  <h1>Call of duty vanguard review</h1>
  <figure>
     <img src="https://www.callofduty.......">
     <figcaption>
        The Campaign Image For The New Call Of Duty
     </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```